# How to convert E numbers in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I created a loop using tic toc in MatLab with the below code

```
tic
for i = val52
    val50(i)=i;
end
toc
```

i then divide the result by 128 (samply frequency) however i get a number which says `2.0516e-05`how can I convert this number into a normal number?

Comment: What do you mean normal number? have you tried `format long`?

Comment: The number is normal. The presentation may not be what you want, but that does not change the value of the number.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want the `e` symbol then you can use `fprintf` instead of `disp`:

```
a= 1/12345678;
formatSpec = 'a is %8.13f \n';
fprintf(formatSpec,a)

>> a is 0.0000000810000
```